# How can I measure a three phase current using a digital multimeter?

Tags: digital-logic

My multimeter does not have provision for AC current measurement. Can I use a CT with my digital multimeter to measure three phase current? If so, how can I do it?

Comment: Simply by measuring all 3 phases separately.

Comment: By using three CT's and three multimeters. Carefully.

Answer (score 1):

Most industrial instrumentation CTs have a 5A (AC) output, so you'll have to add a load resistor to get a sensible reading if your multimeter can't read AC current directly.

Don't operate the CT without a sensible load on it (the maximum burden for the rated accuracy should be specified, maybe something like 0.1 or 0.2 ohm, or perhaps it is specified in VA). Without a load, the CT output terminals can have relatively high voltage on them-- a 6A  or better bridge rectifier with DC output terminals shorted across the output will clamp the output voltage without interfering with the measurement for a burden up to 100 or 150m\$\Omega\$.